# Parallel execution with multiple users in karate

Tags: karate

My requirement is : I want to have parallel execution with say 5 thread. All thread would be creating an entity.I want to have more threads so that text execution time could be less.But I am facing issue as when threads are increasing ,I get error from db saying unable to lock the error as all threads are using same user to create an entity.Is it possible in karate that I can use multiple user credentials so that threads can pick users randomly and create an entity??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution, write the logic in Java to do this and make it a singleton or static method. Then make a call to it from your script something like this:

```
* var MyCode = Java.type('com.myco.MyCode')
* var entity = MyCode.getEntity()
```

So you can keep track of entities created (maybe in a `Set` or `Map`) and re-use as per your wish.

Sorry Karate does not have built-in support for this kind of thing.