# Karate Automation Test Framework - need access to list of features included in run from karate-config.js

Tags: testing, automation, frameworks, karate

From karate-config.js I need to know what .feature files are included in the run.  Is there an easy way to access that?

As a work around, have discovered that if I re-write Karate's Runner.parallel function, I can pass the feature names in an argument:

```
...
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String,Object>();
...
String featureList = "";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   Resource resource = resources.get(i);
   Feature feature = FeatureParser.parse(resource);
   featureList = featureList + feature.getName();
}
args.put("featureList", featureList);
...
CallContext callContext = CallContext.forAsync(feature, options.hooks, options.hookFactory, args, false);
```

However, I dont know how to access the featureList argument from karate-config.js.

Is there an easy way to access the list of feature for a test run from karate-config.js?

Comment: @PeterThomas marked as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported today. This is unlikely to be supported unless you contribute code because no one has ever requested this.

Do note that if you are anyway creating a list of features before you start the test, you can pass that to `karate-config.js` by means of a [Java singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571844/143475).

Comment: Sorry for delay on this, yes this will work.