# How to store entity IDs created with callSingle in karate?

Tags: karate

I'm running tests using the Karate framework.
As a setup step, I need to create some entities using a REST API. I create them using `callSIngle` in karate-config.js:

```
    const result = karate.callSingle('classpath:path/to/createEntities.feature', config)
```

The feature has a `Scenario Outline`, defining various entities that need to be created. The REST API returns an ID for each entity that is created.

How can I save these IDs? I tried several solutions, for example define a variable in the `Background` section of the `Scenario Outline` - doesn't work as it's overwritten by each test and only its last value is returned.

```
Background
    * def ids = {}
.....
Scenario Outline:
....
    * set ids.<index> = response.id
```

In this example, the `result` will only have one value inside the `ids` map, for the last scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a `Scenario Outline` is not designed to be able to accumulate results. You might be able to append to a JSON array, but I leave it to you to experiment.

One thing that may work is if you are into Java, you can append data into some singleton, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571844/143475

Otherwise I recommend you use a `table`, the example here is probably the best simple reference: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#data-driven-features

So you can have a tabular set of data, drive a loop and get the results as an array, ready to return or do whatever.

Comment: Thanks, Peter, I'm sure that table is what I'm looking for, I will try to move the code to using table and hopefully everything will work.