# karate.callSingle cleanup after tests complete - possible enhancement

Tags: karate

We recently implemented karate.callSingle, but noticed that the cache file stays in the target folder after the completion of the test(s).  Is there an option to delete this file or could there be an enhancement to clear any cached files after all tests complete?

Since this cache holds authentication info, we would prefer it not be available after the completion, although some people may prefer that, so an optional field could be a possible solution.  This might be rolled into the same or parallel methods that publish the reports after the end of all tests are completed.

Currently, we are adding the delete of the file to our logout script which runs afterFeature, but we have not found an option to delete the file after multiple features, if the same auth cache is used.

Comment: using this cache is optional, and it is probably simpler to delete it if you use a Java runner class. potentially an area for open-source contributions. you also can consider running your own implementation of the cache using Java code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571844/143475